# Colocar "mãozinha" no iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

Bom dia. Estou abrindo arquivos .png com o iframe e gostaria de saber se é possível colocar aquela **"mãozinha"** que o google maps utiliza para arrastar a imagem dentro do iframe. A utilidade dessa "mãozinha" é para arrastar a imagem para o lado, bem como é o google maps..(Obs: Não é só para mudar o pointer do mouse para uma "mãozinha" e sim para ter as mesmas funções que ela possui no maps..). Valeuu
Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O cara quer mover uma div, eu quero mover elementos dentro de um iframe

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a propriedade `cursor` do `css`, para `hover` use `grab` para `active` use `grabbing`, exemplo...

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor:-moz-grab;
}
div:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor:-moz-grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Para simular em um `iframe`, é necessário colocar uma camada por cima dando assim o efeito desejado...

```css
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .grab-cursor {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
        cursor:-moz-grab;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .grab-cursor:active {
        cursor: grabbing;
        cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
        cursor:-moz-grabbing;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <iframe src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
        <div class="grab-cursor"></div>
    </div>
```

Pode-se também fazer com javascript, para setar em um lugar específico do iframe...

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.body.style.cursor = 'move'; //no body
```

Comment: Entendi como você falou, porém quando tento utilizar junto ao iframe não se aplica nada...

Comment: É mesmo, já editado

Comment: Beleza, ficou show... Agora se eu quiser mover essa imagem com a mãozinha? É possivel?

Comment: Aí já é outra história, devia ter falado antes kk, seria melhor explicar o que realmente quer fazer, pode ser que exista um caminho mais fácil...

Comment: Como eu falei lá na descrição do tópico... A "mãozinha" é para arrastar a imagem para o lado hehe. É como você passou, porém a "mãozinha" deve mover o conteudo dentro do iframe, pois as imagems são grandes e não da de abrir ela inteira no navegador.. Algo tipo o google maps mesmo

Comment: @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin, da maneira que escreveu você fez a referência da "mãozinha" do google maps, que deu a intender que você queria que o cursor do mouse ao ser posicionado sobre o Iframe trocasse para "mãozinha", mas não que deveria ter esse comportamento. Abra outra pergunta explicando melhor o que deseja fazer, pode referenciar essa pergunta nela. E aproveite e explique qual tamanho terá o `iframe`, e o que acontecerá se a imagem for menor que ele, e se for maior o que deve ser feito, e como você quer a interação com a imagem.

Comment: @David agora está melhor.. Reconheço o erro..

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **[jQuery UI Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)** para arrastar elementos na página.

Basta carregar o plugin no seu `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

E depois atribuir o método ao `id` do elemento que você quer arrastar:

```
<img id="draggable"...

<script>
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
</script>
```

Veja exemplo:

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

```css
#draggable {
   cursor: grab;
   cursor: -webkit-grab;
   cursor:-moz-grab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img id="draggable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG" />
```

> O código do jQuery UI e os estilos devem ser inseridos no código-fonte
>   da página do `iframe`.

Comment: Eu tinha tentando utilizar o draggable, porém ele não funciona com iframe.. Se eu jogar a imagem em um <img>, a imagem irá perder a qualidade.. pois é uma imagem de um fluxograma muito grande

Comment: @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin Sim, funciona. Meu teste foi em iframe.

Comment: @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin Vc não falou na pergunta onde ia abrir a imagem. Coloquei em <img> apenas como exemplo.

Comment: se eu tento passar <iframe id="draggable" width="100%" height="1000px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG"></iframe> não funciona.. ou estou viajando?

Comment: @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin Na resposta mostra onde tem que colocar o draggable... o iframe é estático, o que vc vai mover é o conteúdo dele.